# How to use Geom_ma for separated in 2 candle stick

Tags: r

I want to remove a legend "Company" for (--- darkblue) and (--- red).

after I used :

```
geom_ma = geom_ma(aes(color=Company), size=0.7, ma_fun = SMA, n = 5,  na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image]

my code :

## Take the Closing Date of Facebook & Microsoft Stock

```
MICROSOFT <- getSymbols("MSFT", return.class = "data.frame", from = "2021-01-01")

MICROSOFT <- MSFT %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(row.names(.))) %>%
  select(Date, MSFT.Open, MSFT.High, MSFT.Low, MSFT.Close, MSFT.Volume, MSFT.Adjusted)%>%
  rename(Open=MSFT.Open, High=MSFT.High, Low=MSFT.Low, Close=MSFT.Close, Volume=MSFT.Volume, Adjusted=MSFT.Adjusted) %>%
  mutate(Company = "MICROSOFT")


FACEBOOK <- getSymbols("FB", return.class = "data.frame", from = "2021-01-01")

FACEBOOK <- FB %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(row.names(.))) %>%
  select(Date, FB.Open, FB.High, FB.Low, FB.Close, FB.Volume, FB.Adjusted)%>%
  rename(Open=FB.Open, High=FB.High, Low=FB.Low, Close=FB.Close, Volume=FB.Volume, Adjusted=FB.Adjusted) %>%
  mutate(Company = "FACEBOOK")
```

## bind these two time series together

```
time_series_chart <- rbind(FACEBOOK, MICROSOFT)
```

## After binding it into a dataframe, visualize it:

```
time_series_chart %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Close)) +
  
  geom_candlestick(aes(open = Open, high = High, low = Low, close = Close)) +
  
  geom_ma(aes(color=Company), size=0.7, ma_fun = SMA, n = 5,  na.rm = TRUE)+
  
  coord_x_date(xlim = c("2021-01-01", "2021-08-01"))+
  
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", minor_breaks = "1 week", labels = date_format("%B"))+
  
  labs(title = "US Stock Market (NASDAQ) - FACEBOOK VS MICROSOFT" ,
       subtitle = "candlestick charts - Januari 2021 - Agustus 2021" ,
       x = "Month" ,
       y = "Stock Price" )+
  
  theme_minimal()+
  theme_tq_dark() +
  scale_color_tq(theme = "dark")
```

[image]

Comment: Hey I've never seen geom_ma before, that's class. What package is it from ggplot2?

Comment: Hii, the package is "tidyquant".